# How to avoid redundant function calls when pattern matching?

Tags: rust

I want to match several function results without calling all of them if it is not necessary:

```
fn foo() -> bool {
    println!("foo executed");
    true
}

// I want to do something like this
// but there is a redundant function call
match (foo(), foo()) {
    (false, true) => println!("Bingo!"),
    _ => println!("Wrong result"),
}

// No redundant function call
// but less impressive and doubling of wrong result processing
match foo() {
    false => match foo() {
        true => println!("Bingo"),
        _ => println!("Wrong result"),
    },
    _ => println!("Wrong result"),
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
if !foo() && foo() { println!("Bingo") } else { println!("Wrong result") }
```

The "and" (`&&`) and "or" (`||`) logical operators in Rust are short-circuiting, like in most languages.

Since `!foo()` is `false`, the right side of the `&&` will not be evaluated and `foo()` will not be called a second time.
Your macro solution is basically re-inventing short-circuiting, at least for this toy example (maybe it becomes more readable with your actual code...).

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I could beautify the second approach with macro:

```
macro_rules! lazy_match {
    (($condition:expr => $expect:pat) => $on_expected:expr, _ => $other:expr) => (
        match $condition {
            $expect => $on_expected,
            _ => $other,
        }
    );
    (
        ($condition:expr => $expect:pat, $($c:expr => $e:pat),+)
        => $on_expected:expr, _ => $other:expr
    ) => (
        match $condition {
            $expect => lazy_match!(($($c => $e),+) => $on_expected, _ => $other),
            _ => $other,
        }
    );
}

lazy_match! {
    (foo() => false, foo() => true) => println!("Bingo"),
    _ => println!("Wrong result")
};
```